# using absolute paths in typescript for imports

Tags: typescript

my directory structure is:

```
|
|__src
|    |_components
|                |
|                |_A
|                  |_index.tsx
|
|
tsconfig.json
package.json
```

I want to import `A` like this:

import { A } from 'src/components/A';

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es5", "es2015", "es2016", "dom"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "removeComments": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./node_modules/@types/*", "./types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules", "./dist", "src/**/*.test.ts", "src/**/*.test.tsx"]
}
```

But the import does not work and I get the error:

> can't find module 'src/components/A';

Answer (score 80, accepted):

In `tsconfig.json` define `paths` like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

(and you have to import it with name of file as well)

```js
import { A } from 'src/components/A/index'
```

based on the comments no need to import with file name as long as it is called index (With relative paths we can skip the /index)

Comment: node that the trailing `*` in `"src/*": [` is important!

Comment: Any way to not have to import `index`?

Comment: @eivindml i don't know about way how to do it. in one folder you can have multiple files...

Comment: @JurajKocan It could assume `components/A` means `/components/A/index` if the index is present. Vanilla JS with `react-scripts`, `webpack` or where this behavior is defined, supports this out of the box.

Comment: With relative paths we can skip the `/index`: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-mendeleev-11di9

Comment: so it looks like default behavior

Comment: Adding the baseUrl fixed it for me. Perhaps you could emphasize that in your answer along with the paths to make it a little more clear :)

Comment: If you are using webpack, you also need to configure the resolve aliases.
`resolve: { alias: { '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') } }`

Comment: I would like to not need to put 'src' in the path. Any way to change the above import to still import from ./src, but: `import { A } from 'components/A/index'`?

Comment: "components/*": [
        "./src/components/**"
      ],

Comment: @JurajKocan thank for the response, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I made a super simple project to mess with settings until they're correct. Feel free to fork and make a working example! https://github.com/neillindberg/non-relative-path-tsconfig

Comment: That worked for me, and you also need to add this to jest.config.js

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
        "^src/(.*)$": [
            "<rootDir>/src/$1"
        ],
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

Imports with absolute paths work for me using this configuration in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

This is the complete `tsconfig.json` that works for me in CRA app:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: For me, this breaks node_modules imports as it's trying to access from the src folder.

Comment: Could be that some other setting is affecting the node_modules imports. Added a complete tsconfig.json that works for me.

Comment: For me, I had to set `"baseUrl": "./src"`

Comment: @ConradKay you need to leave out the src folder in your imports. For example `import { foo } from 'bar'` and not `import { foo } from 'src/bar'`. This actually annoys me as it makes it hard to read if my imports come from a library or a folder/code that I wrote. I'm currently trying to solve that problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76980414/absolute-path-typescript-react-works-in-ide-linting-but-not-in-cra-runtime