# React Native with TypeScript Error unable to resolve module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I just created a new project with React Native Typescript template. But I found that when I import a new component it throws the following error. My new component is located inside `src/screens/HomeScreen.tsx`

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module `src/screens/HomeScreen` from `App.tsx`: src/screens/HomeScreen could not be found within the project.
```

If I do the same component inline within the App.tsx then it works just fine. But importing from another file causing this issue. I tried to delete and re-create the issue, but still happening.

Can someone help me out on this. Thanks in advance

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import HomeScreen from 'src/screens/HomeScreen';

const App = () => {
  return (
      <HomeScreen/>
  );
};

export default App;
```

HomeScreen.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text} from 'react-native'

const HomeScreen = (): any => {
    return (
        <>
            <Text>test </Text>   
        </>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

The folder structure

[image]

Comment: try adding the extension `HomeScreen.tsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is absolute path import of `HomeScreen`. you can simply change it to

```js
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
```

and it should work. You can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916731/using-absolute-paths-in-typescript-for-imports/55918656).

Comment: Also check this you might like it: https://medium.com/@aleksefo/how-to-setup-module-resolution-and-path-aliases-with-react-native-and-typescript-f4924669780a