# How to import from the opposite direction in vite

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, vite

I have been using create-react-app for a long time, and decided to try out vite.

In webpack, instead of importing a file as follows:

```
import Appbar from '../../../../../../../../../../components/Appbar'
```

I can directly import it as:

```
import Appbar from 'components/Appbar'
```

the way I used to do it is by making a file in the project root directory called `jsconfig.json`, and I write the following:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

This makes webpack think that the root directory is the src directory.

How to make the same thing with vite? vite uses roll-up, but I couldn't find a question as mine, so I decided to ask a new one.

Comment: you can ref at here i think usefull for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68241263/absolute-path-not-working-in-vite-project-react-ts/68250175#68250175

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you might want to try out `import.meta.ROOT_DIR`, this contains the root directory of your project.

For example: You have a module.js located in the src folder and you want to import it from a file in another folder, you can write:

`import moduleName from 'import.meta.ROOT_DIR/src/module.js'`

Comment: First time I read this, but I wanted the absolute path method, and it looks like vite doesn't support it without aliases

Answer (score 0):

Vite now supports absolute imports (sorta). With the [vite-tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths) plugin, you can use absolute imports similar to create-react-app. Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68250175/10032950