# Error in vitest config with NextJS13: failed to resolve import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vitest

I'm integrating `vitest` with a `NextJS13` app, but running into problems with a simple test run.

[image: vitest run error]

Not sure what the problem is, I tried to do some tweaking with the `vitest.config.ts` but no luck. I tried adding the `dir` option, modified the `include` option to grab files from the source file but no luck.

I thought maybe it had to do with the `tsconfig.json` file, but it's still outputting the error.

This is the directory of the file

[image: src directory]

Here are the files in question:

vitest.config.ts

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}'],
    setupFiles: 'setupTests.ts',
    // dir: './src'
    // includeSource: ['src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}'],
  },
});
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNEXT",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "incremental": true,
    // "paths": {
    //     "src": ["./src/*"]
    // }
},
"exclude": ["node_modules"],
"include": ["vitest.config.ts","**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "next-env.d.ts", 
"next.config.js"]
}
```

DataTable.test.tsx - src/common/components/DataTable/DataTable.test.tsx

```
// components

import DataTable from 'src/common/components/DataTable';

// dependencies
import {describe, it} from 'vitest'
import {screen, render} from '@testing-library/react'

describe('DataTable test', () => {

    it('render the app', () => {
        // arrange
            render(<DataTable />)
        // act
            const assetText = screen.getByText("asset")
        // assert
            // expect(assetText).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
})
```

DataTable component - src/common/components/DataTable/DataTable.tsx

```
export const DataTable = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>assets</h1>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Index.tsx - src/common/components/DataTable/index.tsx

```
import { DataTable } from 'src/common/components/DataTable/DataTable';

export default DataTable;
```

I'm new to vitest and nextjs, your help/guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: That's because tsc has failed to find the file that matches the path: it appears to be a custom alias than an actual physical path. What happens when you uncomment the `path` config in your tsconfig?

Comment: @Terry still the same error, I've added that thinking it will help find the src folder, but it's not helping, so I commented it.

Comment: If `DataTable.test.tsx` is in the same directory as `DataTable.tsx`, why not just import it as `import DataTable from './DataTable';`? Otherwise, if you're going to use the paths compiler option in tsconfig.json to get to the root src, you would also need to specify it as `"src/*": ["./src/*"]` to get its subdirectories.

Comment: @M.Desjardins yea that will solve the problem, but I would like keep it as absolute import path. What if the test needs to import files outside its parent directory, in that case you'll end up with this `../../../<file location>`. I have tried the path option in the `tsconfig` file but it's not working either; see the commented line in my `tsconfig` file

Comment: @medev21 That's fair. The paths option in tsconfig should work, but what you have in your tsconfig—`"src": ["./src/*"]`—would only map "src" imports, but not "src/common/components/DataTable". In order to match anything under the "src" directory, you would need to use "src/*" as the key in the paths option, like so: `"src/*": ["./src/*"]`

Comment: @M.Desjardins yea I tried that in the path option, `"src/*": ["./src/*"]`, but for some reason I'm still getting an error. I mean I feel like it should work but not I'm sure why, I'm suspecting there is a missing config in vitest but don't know where exactly; first time working with i, I usually work with jest. This is for education purposes

Comment: In this project, i didn't use the create-next-app command, i just manually imported dependencies, perhaps I'm missing a dependency somewhere. I'm just speculating here

Comment: I wasn't using any templates either, just manually adding what I needed to my test workspace. But I did forget one thing, and that is a plugin like [vite-tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths) (or otherwise manually configuring the module aliases). See [Absolute path not working in Vite project React TS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68250175/1507350) for more information.

Comment: Ah, so I was missing a config/dependency. Thanks for looking into this. I gave it a point to your response.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two things needed here to make the `import DataTable from 'src/common/components/DataTable';` import work:

1. TypeScript needs the paths compilerOption set.
2. Vite needs to have the same alias set.

The "paths" compilerOption in TypeScript will need a `/*` on the end of the "src" key to be able to resolve paths underneath the "src" directory (see [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) reference):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Vite/Vitest will also need to know how to resolve "src/common/components/DataTable", and that would usually be done with the [resolve.alias](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias) setting, but rather than duplicating the alias here, you could also use a plugin, like [vite-tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths), to add the path aliases found in relevant tsconfig.json files:

```js
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

export default {
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths(), react()],
};
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. In NextJs 13.4, the paths field in tsconfig.json is already set. So, adding, tsconfigPaths to the plugin fixed it. Thank you M.