# Organizing my project for good path resolution

Tags: docker, import, package, nest

I am working on a website project. I have 3 main Docker containers: 1 for my backend (NestJS), 1 for frontend (ReactJS + Vite) and 1 for my database (PostgreSQL) (+ 1 adminer but not important).

I needed a type for both my frontend and backend so I thought it would be a good idea to create a shared folder that I would copy both in my back and front containers at init.
I added a package.json to this shared folder to make it a package and facilitate imports, but it does not compile.

For my frontend, I modified my vite.config.ts according to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68250175/22667036) and it seems to work now.

But for my back, i am still struggling with the paths, and it doesnt compile anymore, not even finding my main.ts anymore... (check below for error message)

I connected inside my container and checked that node_modules/@ft-transcendence/shared exists.

I am obviously doing something wrong but I cant identify exactly what.

Here are my dist folder structure + error message, tsconfig.json, dockerfile all from backend, and docker-compose

```
// dist structure + error message from backend
root@f6eeffe91b5b:/app/dist/app/src# cd /app
root@f6eeffe91b5b:/app# ls
Dockerfile     nest-cli.json      prisma       src
README.md      node_modules   run.sh       test
dist           package-lock.json  server.cert  tsconfig.build.json
jest-int.json  package.json   server.key   tsconfig.json
root@f6eeffe91b5b:/app# cd dist
root@f6eeffe91b5b:/app/dist# ls
app  shared  tsconfig.build.tsbuildinfo
root@f6eeffe91b5b:/app/dist# cd app
root@f6eeffe91b5b:/app/dist/app# ls 
prisma  src
root@f6eeffe91b5b:/app/dist/app# cd src
root@f6eeffe91b5b:/app/dist/app/src# ls
app.module.d.ts    auth    game       main.js      password  user
app.module.js      chat    https      main.js.map  prisma    utils
app.module.js.map  friend  main.d.ts  middlewares  test
root@f6eeffe91b5b:/app/dist/app/src# cd /app       
root@f6eeffe91b5b:/app# npm run start

> pong-server@0.0.1 start
> nest start

Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/main'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
root@f6eeffe91b5b:/app#
```

```
// ./backend/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["../shared/*"],
      "@ft-transcendence/shared": ["../shared/types"]
    },
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

```
// ./backend/Dockerfile
# Use an official Node.js runtime as the parent image
FROM node:18

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy packages.json and packages-lock.json then install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

# Install global and local npm packages
RUN npm install -g prisma && \
    npm ci


# Copy the rest of your application to the container
COPY . .

# Generate Prisma client and build the application
RUN npx prisma generate && \
    npm run build

# Update and install system packages in a single layer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    iputils-ping \
    postgresql-client \
    apt-get install -y tree

# Expose port 3030
EXPOSE 3030

# Start the application in development mode
# CMD [ "sh", "run.sh" ]
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

```
// ./docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.4
    container_name: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
      POSTGRES_DB: transcendence
    volumes:
      # Cross-platform(m1 mac): uncomment following line
      - ./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - ft_network

  adminer:
    container_name: adminer
    image: adminer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - ft_network

  back:
    container_name: back
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./backend
    env_file:
      - .env
      - backend/.env
    image: nestjs:test
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
      - ./shared:/shared
    networks:
      - ft_network
  
  front:
    container_name: front
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    env_file:
      - .env
      - frontend/.env
    image: reactjs:test
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    # Cross-platform(m1 mac)
    # command: sh -c "npm rebuild esbuild"
    depends_on:
      - back
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - ./shared:/shared
    networks:
      - ft_network

volumes:
  pgdata: {}

networks:
  ft_network:
```