# cdk synth: Cannot find module when try to switch from relative path import to absolute path import

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I'm switching from relative path import to absolute path import for my CDK package, and get this error when run `cdk synth`:

```
$ cdk synth
Error: Cannot find module 'lib/CodePipelineStack'
```

I followed this [using absolute paths in typescript for imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916731/using-absolute-paths-in-typescript-for-imports) to setup the `baseUrl` and `paths` in `tsconfig.json` file.

Not sure why it is not working.

## More context

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "bin/*": [ "./bin/*" ],
      "lib/*": [ "./lib/*" ],
      "test/*": [ "./test/*" ]
    },
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2018"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cdk.out"
  ]
}
```

I tried `"baseUrl": "./"` and `"baseUrl": "."`, both are not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cdk synth uses `ts-node` under the hood. `ts-node` requires an additional package (`tsconfig-paths`) and some additional configuration to load modules according to your `paths` config in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}
```

Further documentation:
https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#paths-and-baseurl

Your final `tsconfig.json` would look like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "bin/*": [ "./bin/*" ],
      "lib/*": [ "./lib/*" ],
      "test/*": [ "./test/*" ]
    },
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2018"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cdk.out"
  ], 
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}
```

Comment: works, thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

For windows / does not work. You could use either "sh ./.." or use backslash \