# How to fix tsconfig.json module not found?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following folder structure:

```
\---src  
|   \---test
|   |   \---login
|   |       index.ts
|   \---utils
|       |   utilsFuntion.ts
```

i want to import the utilsFuntion from utils filder under src inside the login folder
like this way:
`import {somefuntion} from 'utils/utilsFuntion';`

instead of doing like this :
`import {somefuntion} from '../../../utils/utilsFuntion';`

here is my tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "strict": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmit": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
          "src/*": ["src/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

after i add the src baseUrl and the paths
i change the import like this: `import {somefuntion} from 'utils/utilsFuntion';`
i got error that say: `Error: Cannot find module 'utils/helpFunction`

any idea how to fix this?

i try:

```
./utils/utilsFuntion.ts
./utils/utilsFuntion
utils/utilsFuntion.ts
src/utils/utilsFuntion.ts
src/utils/utilsFuntion
```

Comment: ./utils/utilsFuntion try this

Comment: based on the error output you've posted, it seems that you're trying to import `utils/helpFunction`, but the actual file is `utils/utilsFuntion.js`. Double check spelling and i think you'll be fine =)

Comment: hey, same error

Comment: Question: why are you working with js files in a typescript project? In any case, a first step would be to add `allowJs` in your `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this [using absolute paths in typescript for imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916731/using-absolute-paths-in-typescript-for-imports)

Try this

```
import {somefuntion} from '@src/utils/utilsFuntion';
```

In the tsconfig

```
"paths": {
      "@src/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
```

Comment: hey, same error

Comment: Edited the answer, please try that

Comment: I check your answer but somehow its still dont work :( 
I also saw this post you mantion before and saw this solution but i still get this error

Comment: Try the new edit. In VS code : CTRL + SHIFT + P then type reload or Reload Project might also help

Comment: man still the same error, bruo i think my project is broken somehow :( , i dont know what to do , some of your solution suppose to work. But nothing change i am so mad