# Cannot use absolute paths in typescript nodejs project working with ES Module

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am trying to setup a Nodejs/typescript project and to be able to use Top lvl Await feature I change my setting into a ES module, however i wasn't able to use absolute path in ES module setting.

My directory structure

[image]

In my package.json file I add

```
"type": "module",
```

than my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2022",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
}
```

Prisma.module.ts file

```
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma.service.js';

@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [PrismaService],
  exports: [PrismaService]
})
export class PrismaModule {}
```

For example in auth.service.ts if i use import with relative path like this

```
import { PrismaService } from "../prisma/prisma.service.js";
```

the app work fine with no issue and compile successfully, however if i try to set into an absolute path:

```
import { PrismaService } from "src/prisma/prisma.module.js";
```

Vscode didn't complain and looks like it found the path, but i still get the error below

> Error: Cannot find package 'src' imported from C:\User....

I have found some answer about setting the "path" in tsconfig like

```
"paths": {
   "src/*": ["./src/*"]
 }
```

but same issue as i said vsCode didn't complain about the path, so i wasn't able to figure it out the issue.

Edit: the absolute path work if i set module to commonJs but not in esNext or es2022.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using absolute paths in typescript for imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916731/using-absolute-paths-in-typescript-for-imports)

Comment: Unfortunatly it didn't work, i already tried.

Comment: Hi, any way you figured this out?