# Absolute Path Typescript/React works in IDE/linting but not in CRA Runtime

Tags: reactjs, typescript

## Problem

I was getting linting errors until I setup the `tsconfig.json`. After I did that(as suggested in other answers), the linting errors went away in my IDE(no more squiggly lines), but I am still seeing the following error when I try to run `yarn start` in the runtime.

### Website

[image]

### Powershell

[image]

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@src/views' in 'C:\Projects\temp\src'
ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 5:0-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@src/views' in 'C:\Projects\temp\src'

webpack compiled with 1 error
No issues found.
```

I've looked through multiple similar questions/answers/docs, but none seem to offer the solution for what I am facing. I saw one for react-native, and I got that to work using babel config, but haven't seen anything for react.

## Steps to reproduce error

- install yarn if not done so already: `npx install --global yarn`
- npx create-react-app --template typescript
- delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json
- ensure package.json matches code below
- add/change files/folders as shown in code below
- see directory tree for confirmation...
- run command `yarn` to install node_modules and yarn.lock
- run command `yarn start`

### file/folder directory tree

[image]

### ./src/App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Home } from '@src/views';

function App() {
  return <Home />;
}

export default App;
```

### ./src/views/Home.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Home(): JSX.Element {
  return <div>Home</div>;
}
```

### ./src/views/index.ts

```
export { default as Home } from './Home';
```

### ./package.json

```
{
  "name": "temp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.46",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.4.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint": "^8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-header": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^46.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

### ./tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["/*/index", "/*"],
      "@src/*": ["src/*/index", "src/*"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "App.tsx", "test", "**/*.[jt]s?(x)"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "public", "yarn.lock"]
}
```

### ./tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json"
}
```

### ./.prettierrc

```
{
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "endOfLine": "auto",
  "eslintIntegration": true,
  "printWidth": 120,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "none"
}
```

### ./.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "fetch": false
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.js", "*.mjs"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "off"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["./tsconfig.json"]
      },
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "off"
      }
    }
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": true,
    "ecmaFeatures": { "jsx": true },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "import", "prettier", "react", "react-hooks"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": [
      "error",
      {
        "extendDefaults": true,
        "types": { "{}": false }
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "comma-dangle": "off",
    "indent": "off",
    "indent-legacy": 0,
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "import/named": 0,
    "import/namespace": 0,
    "import/default": 0,
    "import/no-named-as-default-member": 0,
    "no-param-reassign": [2, { "props": false }],
    "no-tabs": ["off", { "allowIndentationTabs": true }],
    "no-use-before-define": "warn",
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "quotes": ["error", "single", { "avoidEscape": true }],
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "off",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/require-default-props": "off",
    "sort-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "ignoreCase": false,
        "ignoreDeclarationSort": true,
        "ignoreMemberSort": false,
        "memberSyntaxSortOrder": ["none", "all", "multiple", "single"]
      }
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "createClass": "createReactClass",
      "pragma": "React",
      "fragment": "Fragment",
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

### ./.eslintignore

```
# Ignore linting on libraries
node_modules

# Don't run lint on dist directory
dist/

# Don't run lint under any test sub directories
test/test
test/coverage
```

### ./.vscode/settings.json

```
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": { "source.fixAll.eslint": true },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```